# MSQLite query with 2 conditions

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite table of 4 columns Id, date, amount, details, type

Type can be "BUDGET", "DAY", "MONTHLY"
I need to sum amount for every months

```
Select substr(date,4) as A, sum(amount) as B 
from records_TB  
where NOT type like '%BUDGET'
group by substr(date,4) 
order by substr(date,-1,7)
```

output correctly as below:

```
08-2020 14752
09-2020 20780
10-2020 21725
11-2020 14236
12-2020 27635
01-2021 25977
02-2021 27004
03-2021 25149
...   ...
```

Now I would like to add one more column for Type="MONTHLY"
I have tried:

```
 Select substr(date,4) as A, sum(amount) as B, 
       (select sum(amount)  from records_TB where type = "MONTHLY" ) fix 
 from records_TB  
 where NOT type like '%BUDGET'
 group by substr(date,4) 
 order by substr(date,-1,7)
```

but it does not work. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like this

```
 Select substr(date,4) as dt, sum(amount) as total, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN type='MONTHLY' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS total_monthly,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type='DAY' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS total_day
 from records_TB  
 where NOT type like '%BUDGET'
 group by substr(date,4) 
 order by substr(date,-1,7)
```